# Prove $\|{v}\|_{W^{m,p}(T)} \le C|T|^{1/p - 1/q} \cdot h_{T}^{-m} \cdot \|{v}\|_{L^{q}(T)}$

Tags: numerical-methods, sobolev-spaces

My professor asked me to derive this inverse estimate:

$\|{v}\|_{W^{m,p}(T)} \le C|T|^{1/p - 1/q} \cdot h_{T}^{l-m} \cdot \|{v}\|_{W^{l,q}(T)}$, for $l \le m$

So I divided the problem into 2 steps: $l=0$ and $l\neq 0$ and I know how to obtain the general result for $l\neq 0$ using the case $l=0$. But to use it I need to prove this inequality first:

$\|{v}\|_{W^{m,p}(T)} \le C|T|^{1/p - 1/q} \cdot h_{T}^{-m} \cdot \|{v}\|_{L^{q}(T)}$

Could someone, please, help me with proof or with any hints?
Thanks!

Comment: Could you please define to us: $T$, $h_T$, $p$ and $q$. I think that $C$ is a universal constant? Also, is $m$ integer?

Comment: @Tomás Oh, I'm sorry. So, I have a triangulation of my domain, $T$ is an element of this triangulation (it's a triangle),  $h_T=diam(T)$ (it is the diameter of circumscribed circle of this triangle), $l,m,p,q$ - integers, $1 \le p,q \le \infty$.

Comment: What are the assumptions on $v$? Also, are you working in $\mathbb{R}^2$? The inequality can't hold for general $v$ and dimension $N$.